# VHF: power resistor to replace dummy load

Tags: radio, ham-radio

I need to check a VHF radio installation @ 155 MHz. For these purposes there exist fairly expensive dummy loads. Can I just use an ordinary power resistor soldered with short wires (3cm) to an appropriate connector instead?

What are the possible problems?

- inductance of the resistor?
- standing waves due to impedance mismatch caused by the wires between the resistor and the connector?

Comment: Ordinary power resistors are wire-wound and NG for RF. What power level? connector type?  RFP-800-50N-E   800W VSWR 1.15:1  DC-500MHz

Comment: @Richman 25W, PL-259. I thought wire-wound resistors might be an issue. That can be avoided with an inductanceless resistor if necessary. I just thought I would ask. What about the "freestyle" wiring? Is it likely to be an issue at a wavelength of about 2m?

Answer (score 1):

The inductance of the resistors will give you a lot more trouble than the wiring.  Carbon resistors can work well enough here, available in 2W size (if they still make them!)  Build up your load by paralleling them.  You may be able to tune out some of any resulting mismatch if the PA (power amp) has adjustments for it.  In an extreme case, build a transmatch to match it.  In practical experience, "close enough" and "for short periods" was good enough and didn't harm the amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Basic transmission line theory indicates you will have inertion and reflection losses even at small fractions of a wavelength and your required accuracy of loading depends on the complex impedance vs frequency.

A simplified block diagram appears below.
[image]
You ought to consider coaxial cable and very short connections to a dummy load with a heat sink and your connector matched to 50 ohms.  Geometry of free-hand wiring affects inductance and may cause unwanted reflections. SO unless you know what you are doing, you may get unexpected results.